# Blank page through Mako template rendering in python / cherrypy

Tags: python, templates, cherrypy, mako

So it finally seems that I could get `Mako` to work.
At least everything done in the console works.
Now I tried to render my `index.html` with `Mako` and all I get is a blank page.
This is the module I call:

```
    def index(self):
    mytemplate = Template(
                    filename='index.html'
                )   
    return mytemplate.render()
```

The html is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<p>This is a test!</p>
<p>Hello, my age is ${30 - 2}.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

So when I call `192.168.0.1:8081/index` (this is the local server setup I run) it starts the function, but the result in my browser is a blank page.

Do I understand `Mako` correctly or did I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In basic usage everything is quite simple, and [well documented](http://docs.makotemplates.org/en/latest/usage.html). Just provide correct paths to the engine.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


import os

import cherrypy
from mako.lookup import TemplateLookup
from mako.template import Template


path   = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
config = {
  'global' : {
    'server.socket_host' : '127.0.0.1',
    'server.socket_port' : 8080,
    'server.thread_pool' : 8
  }
}


lookup = TemplateLookup(directories=[os.path.join(path, 'view')])


class App:

  @cherrypy.expose
  def index(self):
    template = lookup.get_template('index.html')
    return template.render(foo = 'bar')

  @cherrypy.expose  
  def directly(self):
    template = Template(filename = os.path.join(path, 'view', 'index.html'))
    return template.render(foo = 'bar')



if __name__ == '__main__':
  cherrypy.quickstart(App(), '/', config)
```

Along the Python file, create `view` directory and put the following under `index.html`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Title</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
  <p>This is a ${foo} test!</p>
  <p>Hello, my age is ${30 - 2}.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is great.
I don't know in particular where the difference to my server.py was (I'll look it up later), but I'll use yours as a foundation and can finally start to work on the real stuff.

Thank you kindly!

Comment: Can you perhaps explain, what is the difference, between the index and directly module in your example? Both seem to do the same, but I suppose only the "index" module is used when you simply start the server, no?

Comment: ``TemplateLookup`` is a file system lookup. You tell it once where the template root directory is, and later just ask it to get a template, like ``lookup.get_template('user/cabinet.html')``. You can do the same thing by yourself, like in ``directly`` method, specifying full template file name. I gave you the link to the relevant documentation page. Put some effort to understand how your template engine of choice works.

Comment: Well, I already did read through the documentation. This was necessary in trying to get it to work by myself anyway.

I just wanted to clarify if there was a deeper meaning, behind you putting in both modules, since they tend to do the same.

Thanks anyway~

Comment: No problem. To me, [the section about ``TempalteLookup``](http://docs.makotemplates.org/en/latest/usage.html#using-templatelookup) was clear enough, so I wanted to make sure your read it. About "deeper meaning", you use ``Template`` directly when you're fine with doing all the routine by hand. When you automate it, ``TemplateLookup`` is to the rescue (like in your prior question about complete Make solution).